# Segmentation fault. 0xb7d9e768 in memmove () from /lib/libc.so.6

Tags: c++, gdb, segmentation-fault

GDB gives me the above error WRT my C++ program. Nowhere I have used any memory function including new and delete etc.

I want to understand the 'MEANING' of this error.

Comment: Maybe if you posted some code, we'd be able to help you.  But this question is so vague on details that it's going to be closed very quickly.

Comment: Run your executable through _valgrind_ and you'll find out. Basic debugging.

Comment: @Adam I deliberately didn't post code, I just wanted to understand the meaning of this error.

Comment: @Anisha: just becuase you haven't called `memmove()` doesn't mean nothing in your program (such as library functions) will. A call stack trace that GDB should be able to give you when it catches that error (the `backtrace` gdb command) should show you how `memmove()` is being called and should generally show you from where in *your* code that sequence of calls started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If run your program under gdb, you should be able to print out the backtrace and see what part of your code is causing the segmentation fault.  memmove() may being called indirectly through a different system call.

Comment: yeah, backtrace didn't strike me.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that an array operation in your code gets optimized as a call to `memmove`: this is probably why the compiled code uses `memmove`, whereas your source code doesn't.

I think you should check that you are not accessing your arrays out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

`memmove` tried to access (read or write) a memory segment it shouldn't touch.

The reasons can be manifold, but probably pointer corruption. Check it with a debugger, valgrind, check stack trace, etc...

Comment: I haven't used memmove, so from where did it come into question? BTW, I am using plain arrays.

Comment: @Anisha: You might be calling it without realising it, if you munged your memory elsewhere.

Comment: Fire a debugger, check stack trace. Just because you didn't directly call it doesn't mean it will never be called.